# Get the range of a formula in another cell

Tags: range, formula

i need help

I need to obtain the range that I use in a formula in another cell, I show you:

[image]

for the formula that is under "Colores" I need get the range of the formula, touse on "Rango" function.

the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this way I managed to obtain the formula used in a formula from another cell!

[image]

```
Function ConteodeAngulos(Rango As Range)

    Dim rangeValue As String
    Dim openingParen As Integer
    Dim closingParen As Integer
    Dim midParam As Integer

    Dim NumRangUno As String
    Dim LetRangUno As String

    Dim LetRangDos As String
    Dim NumRangDos As String

    Dim RangoEnTexto As String
    Dim RangoTotal As Range

    rangeValue = Rango.Formula

    openingParen = InStr(rangeValue, "(")
    midParam = InStr(rangeValue, ":")
    closingParen = InStr(rangeValue, ")")

    LetRangUno = Mid(rangeValue, openingParen + 1, 1)
    NumRangUno = Mid(rangeValue, openingParen + 2, midParam - openingParen - 2)
    
    LetRangDos = Mid(rangeValue, midParam + 1, 1)
    NumRangDos = Mid(rangeValue, midParam + 2, closingParen - midParam - 2)
    
    RangoEnTexto = """" & LetRangUno & NumRangUno & ":" & LetRangDos & NumRangDos & """"
    MsgBox RangoEnTexto

End Function
```